# is there a maximum font file size for the web?

Tags: web, fonts, size

I want to include font in my website using font face property I found one but the size of the font 100 kb is that too big? is that going to slow my website in anyway?

Comment: Wouldnt' be surprised if ther's a  GB size font file. Also see https://www.google.com/get/noto/#

Answer (score 0):

> I found a font but the size is 100 kb - is that too big?

No, it is not too big. However, there are performance penalties that will increase the bigger the font size is, because the font needs to be downloaded by the user.

There are various [techniques to minimize the problem.](http://css-tricks.com/preventing-the-performance-hit-from-custom-fonts/)

For example, the font isn't downloaded if it isn't used on all pages even if it's referenced. Therefore, you could use the font on only large pages:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Dr Sugiyama';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local("Dr Sugiyama Regular"), local("DrSugiyama-Regular"), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/drsugiyama/v2/rq_8251Ifx6dE1Mq7bUM6brIa-7acMAeDBVuclsi6Gc.woff) format("woff");
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  body {
    font-family: 'Dr Sugiyama', sans-serif;
  }
}
```

You can also look at [compressing your fonts](http://www.phpied.com/gzip-your-font-face-files/).